# Program compiles and runs in intellij but when i build a executable jar it wont work

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, executable-jar

So I'm making a program that connects to a server and downloads a number of images.

The program works as desired when I run it in intelli j, However when I create an executable jar file and click on the program it doesn't work, The program uses intellij's built in gui creator, Would this have anything to do with the problem?

I'm not even sure how I can find out if there are any error. I went into my java options and made the console visible but it never pops up.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What I mean by doesn't work is, When i run the program in intellij a gui pops up instantly. When i click on the jar nothing happens. It like is just an empty jar that does nothing.

EDIT 2: Arcy recommended running in cmd. Hadn't thought of that. This is the resulting error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/jgoodies/forms/la yout/FormLayout
>           at StartMenu.$$$setupUI$$$(StartMenu.java)
>           at StartMenu.(StartMenu.java:42)
>           at RetrieveImage.main(RetrieveImage.java:109) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayou
>   t
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 3 more

Seems like the jgoodies library isn't included in the jar.

Comment: If you have no error, could you please specify "doesn't work"?

Comment: May be you used some jars to run the program and these jars are in intelliJ build path. But when you try to run the jars independently you are mission these jars some some similar kind of stuffs.

Comment: Start a command-line console, run the jar with "java -jar myJar.jar", and look at the resulting error.  And when posting here, ask a question; it is NOT clear what you want us to tell you.

Comment: Never thought of that. I added the error in an edit. Seems like the like the gui library isn't included in the jar

Comment: Try adding the jgoodies jar to your classpath, either via command line args or environment property `CLASSPATH`.